# How to code a selector?

Tags: java, c++, math

I am working on a algorithm but there is a note about a selector. I am not sure what this means but the research paper I am working says:

δ () is a selector, i.e. δ (x) =1 if x>0, else
δ (x) = 0 ;

How does one code this using pseudo code, c++, or Java? 
Thanks

Comment: Can you give us a link to the research paper, or give us a description of the algorithm you're working on, so we can understand how δ is used in context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> δ () is a selector, i.e. δ (x) =1 if x>0, else δ (x) = 0

You just need an if

In pseudocode:

```
delta = function(x)
      {
      if (x > 0)
          return 1
      else
          return 0
      }
```

Comment: thanks nico. i just wanted a simple answer instead of people attacking on something i am new to.

Answer (score 1):

this is a function
pass in x
check if x > 0
if so, return 1
otherwise 
return 0

Answer (score 1):

```
template <class T>
int selector(T x)
{
  return x > 0 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: You can simplify that to `return x > 0;`

Comment: Yes, but to my mind it's better to avoid unnecessary type conversion. Some extra chars don't hurt :)

Answer (score 1):

A *selector* in this context is simply a boolean function which returns 0 (or 1) for all values of x up to a certain point, and then return 1 (or 0) there after.  In other words, a two-steps [step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function).

BTW, given the specific definition of delta in the question, delta is the discrete [**Heaviside Step Function**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) with a value of 0 for x = 0.

Comment: It's the Heaviside function, not the Heavyside function. The name appears to be descriptive, but the function is named after George Heaviside rather than the fact that the function is "heavy" on one side. BTW, Calling this function δ is just terrible; calling it a selector is just as bad. The Heaviside function is H(x) (duh) and is the integral of the delta distribution. The δ distribution is a selector, but it is not a function.

Comment: That's Oliver Heaviside, not George.

Comment: @David: thanks for pointing out the Heavy vs. G. Heaviside tidbit. All these years I assumed it was name after after its image rather than after a person.  BTW, Wikipedia mentions Oliver rather than George.  Also, totally agreed, delta is poor name for it; ' could just be that the paper referred in the question uses the more appropriate sigma, but it is hard to read given the font / codepage.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use an if, you could write (in C#):

Math.Ceiling(Math.Sign(x) * 0.1)

In Java it should be something like this:

Math.ceiling(Math.signum(x) * 0.1)